# Java XSD validation depends on order XSDs are provided

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

Given two XSD schema files:

a.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:include schemaLocation="b.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="TestMessage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="TestSubItem"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

b.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="TestSubItem">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:enumeration value="test"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The following java code successfully validates against the schemas:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

try
{
    String xsdDirectory = "C:\\XSDFiles";
    String xmlString = "<TestMessage xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"> <TestSubItem name=\"test\"/> </TestMessage>";

     Collection<File> xsdFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(xsdDirectory), new String[] { "xsd", "XSD" }, false);
    List<Source> sourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File xsdFile: xsdFiles) {
        sourceList.add(new StreamSource(xsdFile));
    }
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

    // 0 then 1, so add a.xsd then b.xsd (alphabetical)
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new Source[] {sourceList.get(0), sourceList.get(1)});
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    System.out.println("valid");
}
catch (SAXException e)
{
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

But, if you swap around the order the schemas are added to the Source array, so that the XSDs are added in the reverse order (b before a):

```java
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new Source[] {sourceList.get(1), sourceList.get(0)});
```

then you get the following exception:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 68; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'TestMessage'.

This is fine here, because it's an arbitrary example - but if I'm loading the files from a directory and don't know the "correct sort order", then how can I get the code to look for the root element across all files and not just the first one it finds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javadoc of [`newSchema(Source[] schemas)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema-javax.xml.transform.Source:A-):

> parsers may choose to ignore all but the first `<import>` for a given namespace

<sup>*Read the full description in the javadoc for more context information.*</sup>

So only the first file listed is used.

Since `a.xsd` has an `<xs:include>` for `b.xsd`, they both get loaded when `a.xsd` is first.

If `b.xsd` is first, then only `b.xsd` is loaded, which means that `<xs:element name="TestMessage">` is missing, and hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there any way to force it to use all of the provided imports?

Comment: No, because you are not allowed to have multiple different schema files for the same namespace. There is a 1-to-1 relationship between namespaces and XSD files (disregarding versioning). That is why parsers will ignore secondary imports for the same namespace, even if they refer to different XSD files, because they can *safely assume* that the other files have the same content. See rule 1.2 [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#src-import) in the XML Schema Specification.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can instruct schemafactory to go through all imports. Can change depending on underlying implementation.

```
        SchemaFactory factory = schemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/honour-all-schemaLocations", true);
```